# Queue resets after every operation

Tags: c, queue, abstract-data-type

I am working on a queue implementation and something weird is happening. The Enqueue seems to work but the changes are not being registered (the size stays the same at 0). From what I can tell, the code will enqueue an element but immediately forget about it. The output is: 
Data passed: a34
Back befor:(null)
Back a:a34
Data passed: bg
Back befor:(null)
Back a:bg
Print (null)
Print 0
Based on this I'm guessing it's something to do with memory and scope, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.Below is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

typedef struct node_s{
    void* data;
    struct node_s* next;
} node;

// queue structure
typedef struct queue_s{
    node* back;
    node* front;
    int size;
} queue_t;

//helpers
node *newNode(void *data)
{
        //create a new node* with data->data. @return: a node*
        node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = NULL;
        return temp;
}

//deep copy a n2 
node* copy(node* n2){
        node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data=n2->data;
        temp->next=n2->next;
        return temp;
}
queue_t que_create(void)
{
        queue_t new;
        new.size = 0;
        node *front = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        node *back = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        new.front=front;
        new.back=back;
        return new;
}

void que_destroy(queue_t queue)
{
        while (queue.size > 0)
        {
                que_dequeue(queue);
        }
}

void que_clear(queue_t queue)
{
        while (que_size(queue) != 0)
        {
                que_dequeue(queue);
        }
}

void que_enqueue(queue_t queue, void *data)
{
        // Create a new LL node
        printf("Data passed: %s\n",data);
        node *temp = newNode(data);
        // If queue is empty, then new node is front and back 
        if (queue.size == 0){
                printf("Back befor:%s\n",queue.back->data);
                queue.front = copy(temp);
                queue.back = copy(temp);
                queue.size=queue.size+1;
                free(temp);
                printf("Back a:%s\n",queue.back->data);
                return;
        }
        // Add the new node at the end of queue
        queue.back->next = copy(temp);
        queue.back = temp;
        printf("Back2:%s\n",queue.back->data);

         if (data != NULL){
                queue.size=queue.size+1;
        }
        //free(temp);
}

void que_dequeue(queue_t queue)
{
        if (queue.size == 0)
        {
                printf("Deq on an empty q");
                return; //break here
        }
        else if (queue.size == 1)
        {
                //only 1 element
                queue.front = NULL;
                queue.back = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
                node* temp = newNode(NULL);
                temp=queue.front->next;
                queue.front = copy(temp);
                free(temp);
        }
        queue.size=queue.size-1;
}

const void *que_front(const queue_t queue)
{
        //return queue.front->data;
        return queue.front;
}

size_t que_size(queue_t queue)
{
        return (size_t)queue.size;
}

int main(void){
        queue_t q=que_create();
        que_enqueue(q,"a34");
        que_enqueue(q,"bg");
        node* f=(node *)que_front(q);
        printf("Print %s\n",f->data);
        printf("Print %d\n",q.size);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: With `que_enqueue(queue_t queue, ..` you are passing a _copy_ of `queue`. You want to pass a _pointer_: `que_enqueue(queue_t *queue, ...`

Comment: Same with all your other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments by @Paul Ogilvie. C is not "pass by value", so the code will edit a copy of the queue not the actual thing. This is fixed by passing a pointer that will change the value at the address